# Is the integer n in the string s? Is 4 in Ab56c4D? (C++)

Tags: c++, string

Is there a standard function which will return a bool for this?

I'm writing a program that plays the game of life and the user enters two strings, S23 and B3 are examples. In my main loop I just want to check if an integer (the number of living surround cells) is in one of the strings.

Thanks for your help with this question. ;)

Comment: You should be clear about what you mean by "is in". Strings are composed of characters, which are fundamentally integers that identify which character to print. On the other hand (which is what you appear to mean) they may contain a series of characters that **represent** the integer as a numeral that humans recognize.

Comment: Good insight, Karl but should be extremely confusing for a novice as the question is very clear for an expert.

Comment: Agree with Karl Knechtel. Is the integer 4 in the string "abc54dec"? The digit 4 certainly appears, but it can be argued that the only integer in "abc54dec" is 54, and 54 != 4.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Searches the string for the content specified in either str, s or c, and returns the position of the first occurrence in the string.

Return Value:
The position of the first occurrence in the string of the searched content.
If the content is not found, the member value npos is returned.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get a string version of the integer value, then you can try to find it in the other string:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << some_integer;
if (some_string.find(oss.str()) != std::string::npos)
    // match...
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the characters in the string and if the character ( (int)cur_char) ) is between 48 and 57 return true.

Comment: Are all characters between 48 and 57 the number 4?

Comment: You really ought to read the question fully, until you do, the down vote remains!